# Force https on all pages but need one page to be http

Tags: xml, .htaccess, http, https

We have a site that forces every page to a https. However for some silly reason Bing does not support the sitemap to be under a the https so we need to make that page a http rather than forcing it to a https. How would we write this so that bing can crawl the sitemap? Here is the .htaccess code we have currently:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$0 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$0 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^blog_search=
RewriteRule (.*)  https://www.example.com/pagenotfound?  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^blogkeysearch=
RewriteRule (.*)  https://www.example.com/pagenotfound?  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

We need to make the /sitemap.xml appear on http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml rather than being forced to https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 1):

You just exclude it so it doesn't for https for that file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.xml [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Just to make sure I would copy and paste the 3 lines you provided and not change anything else in my code right? Where is the best place to add those lines or does it matter?

Comment: This code is a replacement to your 2nd and 3rd lines of your current file. The 2 lines you have under `RewriteEngine on` will be replaced.

Comment: I see that the $0 is changed to $1 on your last line. Should I also change the $0 to $1 on the 5th and 12th line of my code from above?

Comment: I get in the habit of using $1. Because $0 is the complete match and that's generally not what you want in most rules. In this case you're probably fine.

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer if this working for you.